# flask running function RuntimeError "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread"

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask app (python3.7) that calls a funtion and returns stock data in plain text . 
Script works fine when run in its own .py  ( from stock.screener import Screener  >>  stock_list = Screener(filters=filters, order='price', table='Overview')  . 
In the flask app However I'm getting the following error:
There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
** tried everything on here to get this to work -- asyncio, theading just in the Weeds

tried asyncio, theading.. Im just getting caught in the weeds - Thanks in advance!

```
from flask import Flask
from stock.screener import Screener

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def check_server():
    return "Server is Running!"

@app.route('/test')
def run_screener():

    try:
        r = Screener(filters=['cap_nano','sh_avgvol_o200','sh_price_u10','sh_relvol_o2','sh_short_u30','ta_rsi_os40'], order='price', table='Overview')
        return r
    except Exception as e: 
        return str(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

results expected:

```
No. | Ticker | Company                           | Sector          | Industry                            | Country        | Market Cap | P/E  | Price | Change  | Volume    
--- | ------ | --------------------------------- | --------------- | ----------------------------------- | -------------- | ---------- | ---- | ----- | ------- | ----------
1   | OHGI   | One Horizon Group, Inc.           | Technology      | Application Software                | United Kingdom | 1.44M      | -    | 0.02  | -8.57%  | 660,189   
2   | LODE   | Comstock Mining Inc.              | Basic Materials | Gold                                | USA            | 11.57M     | -    | 0.13  | -9.29%  | 4,668,153 
3   | VIVE   | Viveve Medical, Inc.              | Healthcare      | Medical Appliances & Equipment      | USA            | 6.58M      | -    | 0.13  | -8.47%  | 6,520,180 
4   | UPL    | Ultra Petroleum Corp.             | Basic Materials | Independent Oil & Gas               | USA            | 26.65M     | 0.34 | 0.14  | -21.10% | 14,748,106
```